# How to publish ASP.NET Core project to 32 bit windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a project using ASP.NET CORE (.NET FRAMEWORK 4.6.2)
But it always build into x64 version.
I've set Visual Studio to x86 and add `runtimes:win7-x86` and `platform:x86` inside project.json still not working.
Is there any way I can publish this project to a 32bit Windows 7

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Geolocation": "1.1.1",
    "iTextSharp": "5.5.10",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Sakura.AspNetCore.PagedList.Async": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net462": {}
  },
  "runtimes": { "win7-x86": {}},
  "buildOptions": {
    "platform": "x86",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the settings in the Configuration Manager? Use also the Clean and Rebuild option. What is "still not working"?

Comment: I cleaned and rebuild but nothing happened ,the files in the bin folder still not refreshed.
Inside Configuration manager Active solution platform for both debug and release are set to x86

Comment: Remove the whole bin-folder by hand and rebuild again. You should see some output if there is no builderror.

Comment: I did, but also generate a single win7-x64 folder inside..no x86 version...